# Chrome debugger doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have added a breakpoint to the following code in line 44 `debugger;`. I expected chrome to stop there every time before `console.log("...")` is executed. But to my surprise it stops only one time.

To test the example:

1. Run the snippet below in Chrome
2. Open Chrome Dev Tools
3. Drag an image from another website in the drop area

At this point chrome stops at the breakpoint. But if you look in the console you should see that the `console.log` statement was executed two more times.

I would like to know why this happens. (Threading issue??)

And how I can solve this if I want to debug the code at this line.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#drop-area').on("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
  });

  $('#drop-area').on("dragleave", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
  });

  $('#drop-area').on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var count = 1;
    var dropObj = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    for (var i = 0; i < dropObj.items.length; i++) {
      var aDropItm = dropObj.items[i];
      if (aDropItm.kind == "file") {
        //ignore
      } else {
        aDropItm.getAsString(function(_str) {
          debugger; //The debugger should stop here every time before the string is printed to the console
          console.log("This was called [" + count++ + "] times");
        });
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#drop-area {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop-area">Drop files here...</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** 
I reported this as a bug here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=748923

Comment: The only bugs a quick search of [the Chromium buglist](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) turned up relate to source maps ([ex](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=459499)), which aren't at play here. If no one points out something obvious we're missing, probably worth reporting there. I wouldn't be surprised if it's the result of an optimization, although it's surprising to see code optimized with a `debugger;` statement in it.

Comment: I was not sure if it is a bug or a mistake of mine. I will post it in the buglist if I don't come to a solution.

Comment: Add a link to the chrome bug here so others can find it :)
It might even be considered the "Answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't happen anymore. It seems like it was a bug in chrome.